# @keyframes animation (rotate) and :hover (scale)

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, transition, keyframe

I have a problem with combinig css animation based on @keyframes (rotate) with :hover effect (scale) - and need some help from somebody more experienced then me (i'm rookie - that's obvious).

I would like to create some kind of animated background, where:
1. without any interaction with user: small symbols/letters/icons (whatever) are moving (some of them spinning around, some moving in X or Y axis);
2: when hover: they are also growing (but still moving);
and finally:
3. There is no pause beetwen @keyframe animations.

Right now I have came up with this code https://jsfiddle.net/56q4b9fg/2/ The problem is that at :hover my basic animations starts from the beginning instead of continuing their track. How can I fix this? And how to resolve my third problem with pause after every sequence?

```
.pattern {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(170, 57, 57);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.symbol-1 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
    justify-self: center;  
}

.symbol-2 {
    grid-area: 4 / 3 / 3 / 5;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: start;
}

.downRight {
    animation: downRight 7s infinite;
}

.downRight:hover {
    animation: downRightAndScale 7s infinite;
}

.spin {
    animation: spin 7s infinite;
}

.spin:hover {
    animation: spinAndScale 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes downRight {
    0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0) translateY(0); }
    50% { transform: translateX(20px) translateY(20px); }
}

@keyframes spinAndScale {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.0); }
    10% { transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.1); }
    50% { transform: rotate(180deg) scale(1.5); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.0); }
}

@keyframes downRightAndScale {
    0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) scale(1.0);}
    50% { transform: translateX(20px) translateY(20px) scale(1.5);}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to wrap the `symbol-1` and `symbol-2` in another element and transform this element when hovered. Also use a transition in order to animate it. Take a look at the snippet inserted below.

```css
.pattern {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgb(170, 57, 57);
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

.grid {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
 grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
 justify-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.symbol {
 -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
 transition: all 1000ms ease;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  font-size: 2em
}

.symbol:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.symbol-1 {
 grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 2;
 justify-self: center;
}

.symbol-2 {
 grid-area: 4 / 3 / 3 / 5;
 justify-self: center;
 align-self: start;
}

.downRight {
 animation: downRight 7s infinite;
}

.spin {
 animation: spin 7s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
 100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes downRight {
 0%, 100% { transform: translateX(0) translateY(0); }
 50% { transform: translateX(20px) translateY(20px); }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pattern grid">
    <!-- Wrap the symbols in a div with class "symbol" that scales on hover -->
   <div class="symbol symbol-1"><div class="downRight"> 1 </div></div>
    <div class="symbol symbol-2"><div class="spin"> 2 </div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I trust this solves your problem :)

Comment: Hi (I think I've deleted my last comment by accident - great...). Your solution solved my problem with scale (thanks!), but what about css grid positioning? It looks like it's not working any more :/ I also tried to add grid to .symbol, but then I'm back to square one - with :hover not working... How can I combine this together: animated elements positioned with css grid with :hover?

Comment: Sorry about that, simply swap the classes `symbol-1` and `symbol-2` to their parent elements. Please check out the updated snippet. Also, if my answer solved your problem, then please mark it as the correct answer, thanks! :)